# How do I replace null with 0 in SUM CASE WHEN statement?

Tags: sql, t-sql

I am using a CASE WHEN statement and a SUM function. I want to replace all nulls with 0.

I tried adding a 0 at the end of my statement.

This is my current code

```
select    ID, PT_Number,
          ORGANIZATION,
          [Approved] = sum(case when PT_TYPE = 'Lend' then Approved END),
          [Disbursed] = sum(case when PT_TYPE = 'Give' then Disbursed end),
          [Repaid] = sum(case when PT_TYPE = 'Pay' then Payment end)
from      TABLE1
group by  ID, PT_Number,
          ORGANIZATION
```

This is what I am trying

```
          [Approved] = sum(case when PT_TYPE = 'Lend' then Approved END, 0),
          [Disbursed] = sum(case when PT_TYPE = 'Give' then Disbursed end, 0),
          [Repaid] = sum(case when PT_TYPE = 'Pay' then Payment end, 0)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add an `else` clause:

```
select    ID, PT_Number,
          ORGANIZATION,
          [Approved] = sum(case when PT_TYPE = 'Lend' then Approved else 0 END),
          [Disbursed] = sum(case when PT_TYPE = 'Give' then Disbursed else 0 end),
          [Repaid] = sum(case when PT_TYPE = 'Pay' then Payment else 0 end)
from  TABLE1
group by ID, PT_Number, ORGANIZATION;
```

You could also use `coalesce()` but that seems like overkill.

Comment: Instead of `coalesce`, `ISNULL` seems fine to

Comment: @JochemQuery . . . `COALESCE()` is the standard SQL function for this purpose, so I much prefer it over bespoke SQL extensions such as `ISNULL()`.  In this case though, neither is needed.